# GRUB Customizer stopped working after kernel upgrade

Tags: grub2, kernel

When my PC (running Ubuntu 12.04) updated its Linux kernel from `3.11.0-15-generic` to `3.11.0-18-generic`, GRUB Customizer stopped working. It does not make any changes to the boot menu, even though it shows that it has made changes to the boot menu.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Grub Customizer might help.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-customizer
```